# Three.js: flip image loaded with loadTextureCube

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a legacy code snippet that has long since been part of a web application. The goal is to render a cube from 6 image urls via three.js. The problem is, that the bottom image is flipped around on its y axis. All other sides look fine.

There is no way to flip the original image, since they are provided by an external service. Also when I open the bottom image directly, it is displayed correctly, only in the three.js cube its flipped.

Since I have no prior experience with three.js, I first looked at the documentation for this functionality and realized that the code used in our script is deprecated. unfortunately there is no detailed documentation of the old function (THREE.ImageUtils.loadTextureCube) - or I was simply unable to find it (if someone knows where it is, a link would be great!).

I know that for the long term, a reimplementation to replace all deprecated functions would in order, but since this would take a lot more time (for someone unfamiliar with three.js), I first wanted to check if the problem can be fixed using the existing code base.

I read in various other posts/issues that this is a known issue because three.js for some internal reason defaults to flipY=true on textures. The problem I have is that I don't know (due to lack of documentation) how to change this parameter on one side of the cube only. I expect a function can be applied to the loader that could update this parameter for one of the images or a transformation could be applied to the loaded image afterwards.

I really hope somebody knows (remembers) how this can be achieved with the old loader function.

The following partial code is from my script:

```
// passed list of urls (images.bottom is flipped around)
var urls = [ images.left, images.right, images.top, images.bottom, images.back, images.front ];

  // SCENE
  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  // TEXTURES
  textureCube = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTextureCube( urls );
  textureCube.format = THREE.RGBFormat;
  textureCube.mapping = THREE.CubeReflectionMapping;

  // MATERIALS
  var cubeShader = THREE.ShaderLib[ "cube" ];
  var cubeMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {
    fragmentShader: cubeShader.fragmentShader,
    vertexShader: cubeShader.vertexShader,
    uniforms: cubeShader.uniforms,
    depthWrite: false,
    side: THREE.BackSide
  } );
  cubeMaterial.uniforms[ "tCube" ].value = textureCube;

  var cubeGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(50,50,50);

  cube = new THREE.Mesh( cubeGeometry, cubeMaterial );
  scene.add( cube );

  // RENDER
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.autoClear = false;
  renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
  renderer.setSize( containerWidth, containerHeight );
  renderer.setFaceCulling( THREE.CullFaceNone );
  $container.append( renderer.domElement );
  ...
```

Comment: Do you want to use an outdated revision? Which one do you have?

Comment: it currently is 0.79.0. as i said, its not that I don't want to update eventually, but there is a lot of legacy code and I cannot risk breaking everything by simply updating it to latest. right now I just want to fix this problem if possible, eventually a migration will have to be done of course. 
if I can use the new function as a drop-in replacement with this version it would be fine, but it seems to me that there are more fundamental changes involved. but as i said, a am a newbie with this library so what do I know :)

Comment: You can look at the [migration guide](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/releases?after=r84) (find the 79th revision there and see how many improvements were made since that revision to the latest one :) )